# SNMP OID: How to find the firmware version of a cisco switch from MIB

Tags: snmp, cisco, oid

I am looking for a `OID` to get the firmware version of a `Cisco Switch` using `SNMP`.

I tried the below `MIB` files, i couldn't.

```
OLD-CISCO-CHASSIS-MIB.mib
ENTITY-MIB.my
CISCO-ENTITY-ASSET-MIB
```

Do anybody know the `OID`, if so, kindly post me. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you already did that but try querying the [sysDescr](http://oid-info.com/get/1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1) OID. Usually it contains model number and software information.